# How do I suppress db creation when running a test on my model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, testing, model, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to write a simple test for my model and I don't need a database created.  I added the below file in to prevent database creation

```
myenv:myproject nataliab$ cat lib/tasks/db/test.rake
Rake.application.remove_task 'db:test:prepare'

namespace :db do
  namespace :test do
    task :prepare do |t|
      # rewrite the task to not do anything you don't want
    end
  end
end
```

but when I run my test, I still get the below error

```
myenv:myproject nataliab$ rails test -b test/models/my_model_test.rb
Running via Spring preloader in process 52504
/Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:598:in `async_exec': PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  permission denied for relation schema_migrations (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
: SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:598:in `block in exec_no_cache'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:590:in `block in log'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:583:in `log'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:598:in `exec_no_cache'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:585:in `execute_and_clear'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:103:in `exec_query'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:377:in `select_prepared'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:39:in `select_all'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:95:in `select_all'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.5/lib/active_record/querying.rb:39:in `find_by_sql'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.5/lib/active_record/relation.rb:702:in `exec_queries'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.5/lib/active_record/relation.rb:583:in `load'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.5/lib/active_record/relation.rb:260:in `records'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.5/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:38:in `map'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1031:in `block in get_all_versions'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/deprecation/reporting.rb:36:in `silence'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/deprecation/instance_delegator.rb:20:in `silence'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1029:in `get_all_versions'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1043:in `needs_migration?'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:577:in `load_schema_if_pending!'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:592:in `block in maintain_test_schema!'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:823:in `suppress_messages'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:597:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:592:in `maintain_test_schema!'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/test_help.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/nataliab/Documents/workspace/myproject/test/test_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/nataliab/Documents/workspace/myproject/test/models/my_model_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/test_unit/runner.rb:48:in `block in load_tests'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/test_unit/runner.rb:48:in `each'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/test_unit/runner.rb:48:in `load_tests'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/test_unit/runner.rb:39:in `run'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/commands/test.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:138:in `require_command!'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:95:in `test'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
```

What else do I need to do to prevent any database activities from happening?

Comment: Why would you do this? Just setup a test db using sqllite and be done with it. Nothing useful will come of disabling database activity for your model tests.

Comment: Because we do need the test database creaetd in our test environment, wihch runs PostGres.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what the problem is. If you have a database available for your test environment, why not use it? This feels like an X/Y problem. Whatever issue you're facing, "turning off" the database behind your models for your unit tests is almost certainly not the right answer.

Comment: This feels like you dont know the answer to my question and are just giving me the run-around.  We have dev, test, and prod environments.  But I don't want the test database created when I run my unit tests.

Comment: Nobody is "giving you the run around", I'm trying to help you by figuring out what your actual problem is. Your requirement doesn't make sense, especially with no context.

Answer (score 1):

The ActiveRecord is so tightly coupled with DB that it's not feasible to do. After to work around the requirement to read migrations table, you would have to work around the fact that DB is needed to create your model's attributes (It reads the database columns for that), after that I don't know what's in front of you, but I would bet you won't be even close to done with monkey-patching AR (I might be wrong).

This is just the way rails is done.

What you could do is maybe have models which are inheriting from the AR (tableless models) which are doing whatever you are trying to do, and only use them in other "classic" models?

I, usually, when hitting such hard problem treat it as a hint that you're trying to "go through the wall with your head" (the wall is the framework here which was not designed to handle this) and try to think of a different design (as suggested above: the "tableless" models).

Without more details of your project is hard to suggest anything more concrete.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to test a method without the DB don't put it in a model in the first place. Instead you can place it in a module (a concern in rails parlance):

```
# app/models/concerns/foo.rb
module Foo
  def bar
    'Hello world'
  end
end
```

You can then just simply create a class in your tests which is extended by the module:

```
require "minitest/autorun"
require "active_model/model"

class TestFoo < Minitest::Test
  def setup
    @klass = Class.new do
      include ActiveModel::Model 
      include Foo
    end
  end

  def test_bar
    assert_equal 'Hello world', @klass.new.bar
  end
end
```

Including [ActiveModel::Model](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Model.html) makes the test stand-in behave just like any other model but without the persistence layer.

Otherwise as meagar and meta have already stated trying to test a class that inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base` without a DB is an exercise in futility. The whole idea of unit testing a model without the database is deeply flawed as what ActiveRecords models really do is interact with the DB.

Just writing a single test that covers the actual implementation will lead to better acuity which trumps placating some fundamentalist unit testing ideal any day in my book.